# Event Receiver and Infopath based coloumns

Tags: infopath, event-receivers

An event receiver on an InfoPath library works only when updating columns that are not created by propagating values from Infopath().
 In code below "change" is a regular lib. column and "ApprovalStatus" is infopath based column. The event receiver is a sandbox solution.

Commented-out code is throwing an error:

//properties.AfterProperties["change"] = "test1";

```
        if ( properties.AfterProperties["change"].ToString()  == "test1")
        {
            properties.AfterProperties["Status Indicator"] = field_green.Url;

        }
        //else if (properties.BeforeProperties["ApprovalStatus"].ToString() == "Approval Pending")
        //{
        //    properties.AfterProperties["Status Indicator"] = field_red.Url;
        //}

        //item.Update();
```

Comment: The question is not very clear.Basically after-properties and before-properties doesn't work in all types of event handlers such as synchronous and asynchronous. so revisit their usage and see. Share the error message for additional help.

Comment: OK. SO to simplify: Can i check the AFTER values of infopath coloumn called ["Status Indicator"] . Values for this coloum in itemAdding are always null.

Comment: //string value = properties.AfterProperties["Status Indicator"].ToString(); --this code works for regular column and not for site column where values are for some reason NULL....

Comment: This can only work in Item-Added event. After properties will return null in item adding event. I really doubt if there is any difference in behaviour w.r.to site columns

Comment: Ok then. How do you update item in "Updated" event, i keep geting an exeption about using properties. Please insert code.Thanks

Comment: It seems that you fixed my problem. The code is working now. THanks a lot.\Should any considerations be given to an infinite loop that this update might casue. Update-updated-update....and so on..

Comment: Please follow the below code snippet: this.disableeventfiring()

//your update code..

//this.enableeventfiring() .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after-properties and before-properties doesn't work in all types of SharePoint event handlers such as synchronous and asynchronous.

After properties should be used only when the event context is Item-updated event.

Below code can help in disabling the subsequent events

```
this.disableeventfiring();
 //your update code.. //
this.enableeventfiring();
```